# Calculate shipping costs (with table rates) based on Grand Total of basket? (Magento v1.8)

Tags: shipping, magento-1.8, table-rates

I want to use table rates (Price vs Destination) but **I want the prices to be calculated based on Grand Total not on Subtotal** (which is the default functionality).

I have tried all the settings combinations at Configuration -> Sales -> Tax but neither worked for me.

I want to hardcode it. 
I tried this solution --> [Magento free shipping calculated on grand total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973707/magento-free-shipping-calculated-on-grand-total) but it didn't work for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a valid way of calculating the shipping costs based on grand total (or maybe I'm missing something), because the shipping cost is included in the grand total.
So in theory you can have cases when you can have 2 shipping costs that are valid.
Here is one.

Let's say you have the following rule.
All orders with grand total below 100 have the shipping cost 0 and all orders above that have the shipping cost 5.

If the subtotal is 99, then you qualify for both cases.
If you apply the free shipping then the grand total is still 99 - so it's valid (below 100).
if you apply the shipping cost of 5 then the grand total is 104 - so it's still valid (above 100).

I think the best approach on this is to use the shipping cost based on subtotal and adjust the shipping prices to fit your subtotal intervals.

Comment: I am not sure if you understand OP correctly... I assume he means "subtotal incl. tax" when he says "grand total" (as you correctly pointed out, it would absolutely make no sense otherwise). To calculate the shipping costs based on "subtotal incl. tax" is, imho, the absolute correct way to do it, and I am searching for a way to accomplish it in Magento - by configuration, if possible. Do you know if that's possible?